# Sveltekit return me null value on HTML

Tags: sveltekit

I get "null" value in my html. I know my business name is null. I cannot implement {{array.business?.name || ""}}. Is there any methods to remove "null" value to empty string?

### {array.business?.name}

[this is the result after it render the null data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I1Mn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `ts`? This is notation from typescript.

I make tests, and for me it works.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    const array = {
        business: {}
    }

</script>

{array.name?.foo} --
{array.business?.foo} --
{array.name?.foo ?? '??'} --
{array.name?.foo || '||'} --

{array.business?.foo ?? 'b??'} --
{array.business?.foo || 'b||'} --

{array.business.foo ?? 'c??'} --
{array.business.foo || 'c||'} --
```

result:

```
undefined --
undefined -- 
?? -- 
|| -- 
b?? -- 
b|| -- 
c?? -- 
c|| --
```

Answer (score -1):

Lol I just found the answers but is this the beast practice to do?
what if I have more than 100 json parameters? do I have to make each of them?

[1] https://svelte.dev/repl/095b7f2439dc42d380741350ea11b20f?version=3.22.3

```
<div class="section-title">
 {#if !array.business?.name}
   <h2></h2>
 {:else}
   <h2>{array.business?.name}</h2>
 {/if}
</div>
```